# How to filter a dirty array into a clean stream of data

Tags: php

I have here what I would call a dirty array,
this dirty array needs to be filtered so it is a clean array e.g.

Below is the Array.

```
array
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string 'FIRSTNAME A' (length=7)
  2 => string 'LASTNAME B' (length=10)
  3 => string '2011-12-08 16:15:37' (length=19)
  4 => string '2' (length=1)
  5 => string 'FIRSTNAME B' (length=7)
  6 => string 'LASTNAME B' (length=10)
  7 => string '2011-12-08 16:15:43' (length=19)
  8 => string '3' (length=1)
  9 => string 'FIRSTNAME C' (length=7)
  10 => string 'LASTNAME C' (length=10)
  11 => string '2011-12-08 16:15:48' (length=19)
  12 => string '4' (length=1)
  13 => string 'FIRSTNAME D' (length=7)
  14 => string 'LASTNAME D' (length=10)
  15 => string '2011-12-08 16:15:55' (length=19)
  16 => string '6' (length=1)
  17 => string 'FIRSTNAME E' (length=7)
  18 => string 'LASTNAME E' (length=10)
  19 => string '2011-12-08 16:16:08' (length=19)
```

I want the final output to look like

```
array[0]= 1, FIRSTNAME A, LASTNAME A, DATE

array[1]= 2, FIRSTNAME B, LASTNAME B, DATE

array[2]= 3, FIRSTNAME C, LASTNAME C, DATE

array[3]= 4, FIRSTNAME D, LASTNAME D, DATE

array[4]= 4, FIRSTNAME E, LASTNAME E, DATE
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking or trying to do.

Comment: so...? what are you trying to do with that..? Pls be clear..

Comment: @Jared Farrish, I have updated the question you should be able to understand it now my apologies for asking an incompressible question?

Comment: Where did you got the dirty array first???? I would like to clean it up there itself!!! :) Can you provide more info or some code? ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work

```
$clean = array_chunk($dirty, 4);
```

[more about array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I'm going to take a stab at this. Not completely sure what your asking, but hopefully this will get us in some direction:

```
$cleanArray = array_chunk($dirtyArray,4);

foreach($cleanArray as $value) {
    $finalArray[] = implode(", ",$value);
}

print_r($finalArray);
```